# Getting an Error when i call login function of google-plus

Tags: javascript, firebase, cordova, ionic-framework, google-plus

I'm using ionic4 to create an android/browser application that uses google-plus api to login . 
I managed to set the configuration needed to add the module (webClientId and the reverse ... )

heres the import and configuration

```
import { GooglePlus } from '@ionic-native/google-plus/ngx' ;
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import firebase from 'firebase' ;
export const firebaseConfig2={
  apiKey: "***",
  authDomain: "**-**.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://***-**.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "winwin-***",
  storageBucket: "winwin-****.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "******"
}
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig2)
************
  imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      HttpClientModule,
      HttpModule,
      IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp,{
        tabsPlacement: 'top',
      }),
      IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
      AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig2),
    ],
    *********
providers: [
 ******
    Geolocation,
    GooglePlus,
    AngularFireAuth 

  ]
```

I get the same error in browser and android (cordova run browser / android )

```
LoginPage.html:19 ERROR TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
at GooglePlus.login (index.js:27)
at LoginPage.webpackJsonp.64.LoginPage.loginfirebase (login.ts:45)
at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (LoginPage.html:19)
at handleEvent (core.js:13589)
at callWithDebugContext (core.js:15098)
at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:14685)
at dispatchEvent (core.js:10004)
at core.js:10629
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.js:2628)
at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)

    loginGoogle(){
      this.googleplus.login({
        'webClientId':'****-*****.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        'offline':true
      }).then(res=>{
        firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(res.idToken))
        .then(suc=>{
          alert('HALLALOUYA')
          }).catch(ns=>{
            alert ('not succ')
          })
        })

    }
```

The problem that I didn't find anyone with this error
can't tell if I have a plugin version error or I have messed up the configuration.

Comment: Can you update your question to show how you are declaring and initializing `googleplus`?

Comment: @Prisoner , sorry i forgot to add that ? Done .

Answer (score 1):

Using the Google Plus Login will not be supported starting in March 2019, and may stop working before then. You should [migrate](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/quick-migration-guide) to Google Sign In.

Comment: that's strange i didn't see any deprecated warning in log or while installing the plugin . do you have the newer documentation for Google Sign In ?

Comment: The link in your comment doesn't show the documentation to use the api with ionic cordova . And when i go to guide it shows the deprecated documentation again ....

Answer (score 0):

For me this is a version mismatch when installing @ionic-native/google-plus

If you are not on Ionic 5, you need to get an earlier version. Which one exactly?

For Ionic 3.9 `npm i @ionic-native/google-plus@4.16` works.

For 4.0 I imagine you can try 4.20.0. The key is after you install it, look in `node_modules\@ionic-native\google-plus\package.json` and check under `peepDependencies` to see that your project matches all the requirements.